# MvvmCross Sqlite UWP

Tags: sqlite, uwp, mvvmcross

I have created Android application using MvvmCross now I would like to add UWP project also. First thing which stopped me is SQLite. While app start I have following error:

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: 'Failed to
>   resolve parameter for parameter factory of type
>   IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory when creating
>   Theseus.Mobile.Core.Services.LocalStorage.LocalStorageService'

I am reading google since 2 hours and adding wierd references but still nothing works. Did somone faced the problem ?

Comment: Did you seen this [sample](https://github.com/artemkalinovsky/MvxSqlite)?

Comment: This is Droid and iOS